# Use a path variable in an Eclipse runtime configuration's environment variable?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to use Eclipse's Path Variables inside Environment Variables, that are defined in a runtime configuration?

My service gets the root adaptation folder from its environment, from the variable "ADAPTATION_ROOT". So I defined the following Environment Variable in the launcher:

```
ADAPTATION_ROOT    ${WORKSPACE_LOC}/adaptation/dev
```

When I debug the service in Eclipse, I get an error:

```
Reference to undefined variable WORKSPACE_LOC
```

Which seems to indicate that I can't use this variable. But is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is very embarrassing, as the obvious didn't occur to me! The answer was to use lower case:

```
ADAPTATION_ROOT    ${workspace_loc}/adaptation/dev
```

Enjoy!